# check if string contains image url and replace the url by splitting "-" and replace arr[0] with new url url on front and concate with arr[1]

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

check if string contains image url and replace the url by splitting "-" and replace arr[0] with new url on front and concate with arr[1]

The below is an html content it may contains one or many url's hostname should be replace in mvc

http://differenthostname/-/media/53F34BB24C054D72A9CE7B1CB06986CE.ashx

http://newhostname/-/media/53F34BB24C054D72A9CE7B1CB06986CE.ashx

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
string[] _temp = IMAGEURL.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
IMAGEURL = "http://newhostname/" + _temp[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var str = 'assets/images/image-01.jpg';

if (str.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null) { //url is image
    var arr = str.split('-');
    str = 'assets/images/new_url-'+arr[1];
} else {
    alert('Not an image!');
}

//result:
//str = "assets/images/new_url-01.jpg"
```